# how to re-insert all of the existing fields but only change one field data in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have bunch of data in one table, for example lets say I have a table with four  columns.

id,name,age,address.

`id` stays the same but all the other fields changes. i.e it will look something like this.

```
id      name         age        address
1       steve        20         test address 1 
1       mark         21         test address 2
```

and now I want to have the same data set but only change the id, for example everything will stay the same but only the id changes to look something like this:

```
id       name          age        address
1        steve         20         test address 1
1        mark          21         test address 2
2        steve         20         test address 1
2        mark          21         test address 2
```

but I don't want to insert it one field at a time, because I have 100's of fields and to do it like that will waste so much time.

so my question is how can i do this as easily as possible in Postgres?

I forgot to mention the other fields are not set by default and I want to copy the data from a specific field id, so in general it should be like. first I want to grab all the fields from a specific id, then insert these fields again but now with the new id which is 2 for example.

Comment: "insert into table select id+1, name, age, address from table"? (When you say 100's of fields, do you mean 100's of rows or 100's of columns?)

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention the other fields are not set by default and i want to copy the data from a specific field id, so in general it should be like.                      first i want to grab all the fields from a specific id, then insert these fields again but now with the new id which is 2 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into table(id,name,age,address) select 2,name,age,address from table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table list (id int,name text,age int,address text);


insert into list values (1,'steve',20,'AAAAAAAAA');
insert into list values (1,'mark',21,'BBBBBBBBB');
```

Now create a function for the *INSERT* Operation:

```
create or replace function ins_list(_updateID int ,_getID int) returns void as
$$
-- _updateID : - the new ID that you want to insert(ex. 2)
-- _getID : - the ID that you need to search to get values from name,age,address (ex.1)
insert into list (id,name,age,address) select _updateID,name,age,address from list where id  = _getID
$$
language sql
```

to Insert you just need to call like

```
select ins_list(2,1);
```